# Using INDEX MATCH to return multiple matching values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I'm trying to return values from multiple matches when using INDEX MATCH in Excel. I currently have a worksheet called **Data** which has a **House name** column and **Student** column (please see the attached screenshot). Each row has a House name as well as a Student name. I have another sheet called **lookup** where I have cells for each House name and in the cell next to it, I want to return all the matching student names for the house, separated by commas.

I'm using an INDEX MATCH call against each House name **=INDEX(Data!B:B,MATCH(lookup!E2,Data!A:A,0))**.
But INDEX MATCH only returns the first matching student name, but I want it to return all the matching Student names against the House name from the data sheet in the cell, separated by commas like in ARRAYTOTEXT. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You'd need `FILTER()` and `TEXTJOIN()` for this.

Comment: @JvdV thank you, I have tried this =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(Data!B:B,Data!A:A=lookup!E2)) but it returns a #VALUE error.

Comment: Not sure where that error would come from. If you wouldn't have `FILTER()` available or if the function can't find anything the error would be different. When attempted on your sample data, your above formula worked fine for me.

Comment: @JvdV Hi, one of the columns being searched (House name) had a #VALUE error, so TEXTJOIN returned a #VALUE error too. Fixed that and now everything works fine! Thank you!